# Queue operations in Java

Tags: java, oop, generics, queue

I have an assignment to do that involves creating and performing operations on a queue... 
In the instruction he starts off by saying this...

```
Node Class: You will extend the following class for (some of) the questions below.
   public class Node<T>{
       protected      T  data;
       protected Node<T> next; 
   }
Implement the QUEUE (FIFO) abstract data type. For this, you will create a class called Queue that extends Node<T>. Your class should have the following methods:

public void enqueue(Node<T> item)
// Purpose: adds item to the queue
// Preconditions:  item should exists (not be null)
// Postconditions: item is added to the end of the queue
//                 the size of the queue is increased by 1
```

... and so on with a few more pages of requirements etc...

I would like to know a few things that I do not understand... 
what does `public class Node<T>` mean? (italic part).

Also, there are many more methods other than the enqueue one, so I'm assuming proper design would require me creating the queue outside this method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: so it means this class Node has a parameter of type T?

Comment: Basically you can instantiate your class with any object e.g. Node<Integer>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Node<T>` allows you to make all the nodes of your queue the same type, and to specify that type at compile time.

For example, you could have nodes of type:

- int
- String
- YourDefinedJobType

(But only the single type that you specify could go on the queue.)

The generic notation would require that only nodes of that type will be queued, which can be quite handy, because you will throw a runtime error if you set up `Node<String>` and you try to add a node of YourDefinedJobType.

Second, when you get `Node<String>` working, you will get `Node<YourDefinedJobType>` working without any additional queue code.

Further, you are guaranteed to have nodes of the correct type and will not have to cast them.

There's a sample chapter from Joshua Bloch's book, *Effective Java*, that deals with generics. It's certainly worth a read and will answer your questions about generics.